# Disable button based on attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which processes data and puts it in to a csv. A user can add multiple rows to the form to add a new item. To make this a unique item the id is incremented by 1 (ex. item[0] goes to item[1](http://jsfiddle.net/ejs06003/V2TAt/))

The form works great but I am trying to add a delete / remove button. It works except I don't want it to remove the very last item.

Below is the code I am using. I am having trouble as this if statement breaks the add crew button.

```
    $('#btnDelelte').click(function () {
        //remove the last form item
        $('.questions:last-child').remove();

        // if only element that remains as ID == 0, disable the "remove" button
        if ($('.questions:last-child').attr('id' == 0) 
            $('#btnDelelte').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
```

If you comment out the if statement, and run the jsfiddle all the buttons work but you are able to delete the last form area.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejs06003/V2TAt/)

Comment: Please take the time to check if you have any syntax errors in your code before posting. Even in your jsfiddle link - the syntax error is right there in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the console it says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Looking at where the error is you can see the attribute method is not properly closed.

```
if ($('.questions:last-child').attr('id' == 0)
```

It should be

```
if ($('.questions:last-child').attr('id') == 0) 
                                        ^
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see the syntax error. I also not realize I was looking at it wrong as the ID [0] is a prefix on a longer ID. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#btnDelelte').click(function () {           
       if($('.questions').length > 1){
           $('.questions:last-child').remove();
       }               
       });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V2TAt/4/

Comment: Edit: What I should say is that if you add a new set of questions, delete it and then add another it does not incriment the idname[#]. It just keeps adding questions with the same idname[#].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Replace

```
if ($('.questions:last-child').attr('id' == 0) 
            $('#btnDelelte').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

with

```
if ($('.questions:last-child select').attr('id') == "town[0]")
           $('#btnDelelte').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Edit: What I should say is that if you add a new set of questions, delete it and then add another it does not incriment the idname[#]. It just keeps adding questions with the same idname[#].